# How do I use vue router with laravel when each are in a seperate folders?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-router

I have project I'm working on and I'm using both Laravel & Vue, I want to use vue's Router, currently I have them both running as

> ProjectName
>       -frontend
>       -backend

npm run serve is running for vue port 8080 and php artisan serve is running on 5000 for laravel.

How can I make laravel use vue's router instead when vue is outside laravel's scope?

Comment: do you want two servers or one server?

Comment: one, using them on 1 vps